# How can I replace a string pattern with blank in hive?

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I have a string as:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=41.892532+-87.63811&zoom=11&scale=2&size=280x320&maptype=roadmap&format=png&visual_refresh=true%7C&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x8000ff%7Clabel:1%7C2413+S+State+St++Chicago+IL+60616%7C&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x8000ff%7Clabel:2%7C3000+N+Halsted+St++Chicago+IL+60657%7C&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x8000ff%7Clabel:3%7C++++&key=AIzaSyBNEAQcC5niAEeiP3zkA_nuWGvtl0IOEs4
```

I want to replace the '++++' pattern at the end with blank and not the single occurrence of '+'. Tried using regexp_replace and translate functions in hive but that replaces all the single occurrences of '+' as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
regexp_replace(string,'[+]{4}','')
```

Pattern '[+]{4}' means + caracter four times.

Test:

```
select regexp_replace('++markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x8000ff%7Clabel:3%7C++++&','[+]{4}','');
```

Result:

```
OK
++markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0x8000ff%7Clabel:3%7C&
```

Answer (score 0):

Dod you try this?

```
replace(string, '++++', '')
```

Admittedly, this will replace all occurrences of `'++++'`, but your string only has one of them.